# X-UA-Compatible IE=7 problems in IE 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

I have html like below, when I'm trying to browse this in IE9, nothing will come up until you mouseover the div. if I change the "X-UA-Compatible" to "IE=8" it will show up.
your suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <table>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="height:400px; width:400px">
              <OBJECT ID="Player" HEIGHT="100%" WIDTH="100%" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
             </OBJECT>
           </div>
       </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```